# Creating a drop-down menu in Javascript - Nothing showing on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to create a drop-down menu in javascript, html and css however when I run the code nothing is showing on canvas. Is it because the files aren't communicating with each other correctly?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DropdownMenu</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Stylesheetdropdown.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="5000">
        </canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='DropdownMenu.js'></script>
    </body>
    <body>
    <div class = "dropdown">
    <button onclick = "dropdown()" class = "drpdwnbtn">Menu</button>
        <div id = "myMenu" class = "drpdwncntnt">
            <p>100</p>
            <p>200</p>
            <p>300</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("myMenu").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.drpdwnbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("drpdwncntnt"),
            i,
            openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i += 1) {
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

CSS:

```
.drpdwnbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.drpdwnbtn:hover, .drpdwnbtn:focus {
    background-color: #E0FFFF;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.drpdwncntnt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.drpdwncntnt a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

Comment: canvas is taking(5000,5000) width and height so your menu button coming down. bdw use one body tag only.

Comment: You're also not doing anything with the canvas in the JavaScript.

Comment: What are you trying to get the canvas to show? You don't have any code that adds anything to the canvas

Comment: Deleted canvas line - works fine now.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I have another function that draws out a sine wave on the screen and I want the menu to change the wavelength of the sine wave. Thought it would be simpler to leave that out, however.

Comment: So how did taking out the canvas solve the problem of you not being able to draw to the canvas? To be clear, the dropdown menu you created doesn't have anything to do with drawing to your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas was over your menu div, your html should look like:

```
<div class = "dropdown">
<button onclick = "dropdown()" class = "drpdwnbtn">Menu</button>
    <div id = "myMenu" class = "drpdwncntnt">
        <p>100</p>
        <p>200</p>
        <p>300</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="5000">
    </canvas>
```

, so here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ahpook4p/